# ¿Cómo comprobar si existe registro en la base de datos con PDO - PHP?

Tags: php, pdo

Es para un formulario de registro, necesito hacer que si existe, no permita y dispare un else. Pero he buscado mucho en este foro y en otros y no me han servido.

El error es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetchColum() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pcu\registrarme\index.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pcu\registrarme\index.php on line 26

```
<?php
$existenciausql=("SELECT * FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = ':u' or Email = ':e'");
$stmt1=$db->prepare($existenciausql);
$stmt1->execute(array(":u" => $u, ":e" => $e));
if($stmt1->fetchColum()==0)
{
   // INSERT
}
else{echo "Ya existe";}
?>
```

Comment: probaste con rowCount ? .  http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php . una vez ejecutado el execute, con el rowcount podrías verificar si el select tiene uno o mas registros.. si es asi, es porqu existe.

Comment: ¿Podrías ayudarme con el tipeo?

Comment: perdón , lo vi tarde.!

Comment: @Morderisk mejor opción que el `rowCount` es la que detallé en mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

La función [fetchColumn($numerocolumna)](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) , lo que retorna es el **valor** del número de la columna pasada por parámetro, si no pasa ningún parámetro, retornará siempre la primera.

Como usted realiza un `select *` , no podrá validar si existe o no el registro, lo que puede realizar es modificar la consulta y utilizar `count(*)` que retorne la cantidad de registros. *(ahí si sería útil utilizar fetchColumn para obtener la cantidad)*

```
$existenciausql=("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sv_nicks WHERE Nick = :u or Email = :e");
$stmt1= $db->prepare($existenciausql);
$stmt1->execute(array(":u" => $u, ":e" => $e));
if($stmt1->fetchColumn() > 0){
    echo "Existe";
}
```