# Contar filas de una consulta en MySQL con C#

Tags: c#, mysql

La idea es validar que no se ingresen registros iguales, están amarrados por un campo llamado certificado.

Tengo el siguiente código para

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM prueba.facturas where Certificado = @certificado", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@certificado", xCertificado);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (consulta es =  0){

}
```

leí que en PHP existe la función `mysql_num_rows` ¿Existe algo similar para C#?

Comment: Utiliza el COUNT en tu consulta de SQL para contar los registros que existan según el certificado `SELECT COUNT(*) AS Cuantos FROM prueba.facturas where Certificado = @certificado` ya solo obtén el valor de la columna Cuantos y haces la comparación

Comment: Cabe aclarar que para PHP `mysql_num_rows` [no es lo ideal para contar registros o la existencia de un registro en una base de datos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/233372/c%C3%B3mo-comprobar-si-existe-registro-en-la-base-de-datos-con-pdo-php/233382#233382) ;)

Answer (score 1):

La ideal sería utilizar [ExecuteScalar()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=netframework-4.7.2) para obtener el valor  de la primera fila, para esto su consulta debe retornar el total de filas haciendo uso de `count(*)`

```
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM prueba.facturas where Certificado = @certificado", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@certificado", xCertificado);
if(cmd.ExecuteScalar() > 0 ) { existe }
```

Comment: Creo que solo funciona con SQL y por ahora es con mysql

Comment: @JuanPabloSolana mysql ES sql. donde tenes la confusion? eso que escribe joel aca funciona en cualquier base de datos.

Comment: a que no funciona con mysql :( o me faltará algo ¿?

Comment: tienen razón el código funciona, me marcaba que no puede convertir un binario en entero

Comment: Sería bueno que expliquen el voto negativo para mejorar la respuesta 3:) o propongan una mejor solución.

Answer (score -1):

lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```js
cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM prueba.facturas where Certificado = @certificado", conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@certificado", xCertificado);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
string getValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
 if (getValue =="0"){ }
```

Espero que a alguien le ayude, gracias a todos por su ayuda.

Comment: Parece que lo resolvió con mi respuesta. 3:) Me alegra que fuese así.

Comment: Es correcto, lo resolví con el código de arriba. Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Juan Pablo, si la respuesta resolvió el problema puede marcarla como aceptada, recomiendo leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)